# How do I use a template with a linked list implementation?

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm just starting out with templates and am having an issue where I keep getting a segmentation fault. I've narrowed the problem down to the fact that my data within my Node struct is a template, and when I go to set that data, it does not work. I tested this by setting my data to an int, and manually setting it that way and that worked, but I'd like it to be a template.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

template<class T>
class Game // made a class so it was easier to keep track of the head pointer
{
private:

struct Node
{
T cmdName; // command name
T cmdDesc; // command description
struct Node* pNext;
};

struct Node* pHead = NULL;

public: 

Game()
{
    T lineTemp, tempName, tempDesc;
    std::ifstream dataFile;
   
    dataFile.open("commands.csv");

     while(std::getline(dataFile, lineTemp))
    {
        std::getline(dataFile, lineTemp);
        std::istringstream ss(lineTemp); // using string stream to split the string pulled in from the csv file (idk how else to do this)

        std::getline(ss, tempName, ',');
        std::getline(ss, tempDesc, ',');

        insert_data_front(tempName, tempDesc);
    }
}

// all functions and their definitions will be here because you shouldnt split the files for template functions (i think?)
void insert_data_front(T cmdName_c, T cmdDesc_c)
{
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // returns a pointer the same size as the data block needed

    newNode->cmdName = cmdName_c; // < --- HERES THE ISSUE 
    newNode->cmdDesc = cmdDesc_c;
    newNode->pNext = pHead;
    pHead = newNode;
}
};
```

The issue is the function `insert_data_front`, how would I go about this? Thanks

Comment: The template's not going to cause a segfault. Check the linked list logic.

Comment: Duplicate is "right", but probably for a different reason than inheritance. For example, if `T` is a a class like `std::string` that lives and dies by the initialization work done by its constructor, `newNode->cmdName = cmdName_c;` is going to be quite an adventure.

Comment: Anyway, the general rule of thumb is don't use `malloc` in C++. You'll find the exceptions later if you ever deep dive into the Standard Library's containers or otherwise find yourself writing interesting code with peculiar memory allocation and reallocation requirements.

Comment: If `T` is not a Plain Old Data (POD) type, it will consist of pointers etc, and any copying and initialisation will not be performed properly (e.g. if T is a std::string).  Which is why you must use `new` as opposed to `malloc` in order to ensure it's done properly.